# Passing a CMake variable to C++ source code

Tags: c++, cmake

First of all, I already read [How to read a CMake Variable in C++ source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7900661/how-to-read-a-cmake-variable-in-c-source-code), and I don't really know if it can help me.

Second, my question. Top level CMakeLists.txt says `SET( MY_VAR /some/path )` and in top level source.cpp I need to achieve somehow a `std::string` containing `/some/path/to/files` naturally using `MY_VAR` value.

Comment: Possible no-reading-skills user

Comment: It says quite clearly how to pass a value from Cmake to C++ in that answer using macros.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the `configure_file(filename output_file)` command. It replaces something like `${VARIABLE}` or `@VARIABLE@` in file `filename` with the actual value of cmake variable `VARIABLE` and writes the result to `output_file`.

So, you can write something like

```
// in C++ code
std::string my_var = "@MY_VAR@";

# in CMakeLists.txt
configure_file(filename.h.in filename.h)
```

Also, I think it is a good idea for the output file to be generated somewhere inside build directory (and its' containing directory added to include paths).

[configure_file in cmake documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#command:configure_file)

Comment: Oh, $Deity. Now I *know* I want to stay well clear from CMake. Thanks!

Comment: This almost worked. I mean, it did, but it replaced forever @VARIABLE@ with the value of VARIABLE. What if I change the value of VARIABLE? There's no more @VARIABLE@ to be replaced in next compilation.

Comment: What I ment by 'forever' is that I opened source.cpp and I saw no `@VARIABLE@`, but `/some/path` now.

Comment: @Javier: if the variable's value changes, the file will be regenerated when cmake will be called (and it is called automatically if building with cmake-generated makefiles).

Comment: @Javier: this command should be used to generate a real source file from a some kind of template file, and not to call it like `configure_file(source.cpp source.cpp)`.

Answer (score 18):

```
add_executable(myexe main.cpp)
if (MY_VAR)
    target_compile_definitions(myexe PRIVATE MY_VAR=${MY_VAR})
endif()
```

EDIT: Then the variable would be available in C++ code like that:

```
#ifdef MY_VAR
std::cout << MY_VAR << std::endl;
#endif
```

Comment: So this way I can use MY_VAR in .cpp?

Comment: Yes. The MY_VAR=${MY_VAR} is of the form 'CPP_NAME=${CMAKE_NAME}'. The two are the same in my example though.

Comment: Can't do this in version 2.8.9. And I'm not able to upgrade.

Comment: It's still the right answer :)

Answer (score -3):

The only way to pass in values during compilation is by passing a macro. E.g., if CMake sets a macro called `$(MY_VAR)` (as `make(1)` does):

```
g++ -DMY_VAR=$(MY_VAR) .... xxx.cc
```

and `xxx.cc` uses `MY_VAR` as it wishes.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a noob in CMake. Could you tell me what's the code to do that?

Comment: @Javier, oops. Fixed to use the macro (I assume CMake uses `make(1)` syntax here...)

Comment: That's not the only way, look at my answer.

Comment: @lisyarus, that is mangling the file to be compiled. I stand by my assertion.

Comment: @vonbrand: what do you mean saying "mangling the file to be compiled" ?

Comment: You aren't compiling the given file, it is being edited into the file to be compiled.

Comment: @vonbrand: if the value it got from cmake, I assume this value it some configuration variable and does not change between builds, and it's better to put it into the code once rather then ad it during every compilation.

Comment: Well, actually I would like to put it during every compilation, because the variable may be changed (not often though).

Comment: @Javier: that's not a problem: the file will be regenerated if the variable changes.