# Use variable from CMAKE in C++

Tags: c++, cmake

I want to use a value declared in my CMakeLists.txt in my C++ code. I've tried to do like that :

```
ADD_DEFINITIONS( -D_MYVAR=1 )
```

and

```
#if -D_MYVAR == 1
    #define var "someone"
#else
    #define var "nobody"
#endif
int main(){
    std::cout << "hello" << var << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But it doesn't work, and I don't understand why. Maybe I don't use ADD_DEFINITIONS correctly...

Ideally, I wish do something like that :

```
ADD_DEFINITIONS( -D_MYVAR=\"someone\" )
```

and

```
#define var D_MYVAR

int main(){
    std::cout << "hello" << var << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Is it possible ?

Thanks !

Comment: `#if -D_MYVAR == 1` should be `#if _MYVAR == 1`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read a CMake Variable in C++ source code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7900661/how-to-read-a-cmake-variable-in-c-source-code)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
add_definitions ( -DVARNAME=... )
```

is the correct way of using add_definitions.

To check for a constant then, use

```
#ifdef VARNAME
...
#endif
```

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to [πάντα ῥεῖ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1413395/%CF%80%CE%AC%CE%BD%CF%84%CE%B1-%E1%BF%A5%CE%B5%E1%BF%96)

His solution works for my first question, and I've could do that :

**CMakeLists.txt:**

```
ADD_DEFINITIONS( -D_VAR=\"myValue\" )
```

**main.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>

#ifdef _VAR
    #define TXT _VAR
#else
    #define TXT "nobody"
#endif

int main(){
    std::cout << "hello " << TXT << " !" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As of CMake `3.12` `add_definitions` has been [superseeded by other alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24488416/10662021).

For this question, you should use `add_compile_definitions` in the same way you were using `add_definitions`:

```
add_compile_definitions( MY_VAR )
```

(note that the `-D` is not needed anymore).

And then in your `*.cpp` file:

```cpp
#ifdef MY_VAR
// do something if var defined
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a much more elegant way to do this, that does not require to go through the C/C++ preprocessor. (I hate `#ifdef`...)

In `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set( myvar "somebody" )

# Replaces occurrences of @cmake_variable@ with the variable's contents.
# Input is ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/main.cpp.in,
# output is ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/main.cpp
configure_file( main.cpp.in main.cpp @ONLY )
```

In `main.cpp.in`:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){
    // myvar below gets replaced
    std::cout << "hello @myvar@" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Note, however, that a file so configured gets saved in `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}`, so you have to prefix it as such when listing it in the source files (as those default to `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}`):

```
add_library( myproject foo.cpp bar.cpp ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/main.cpp )
```

Comment: Why you hate ifdef ? This is equivalent or maybe worse as it ties your program even more with cmake and on the other hand a definition could exist on a cpp folder ,this doesn't

Comment: @SpyrosMourelatos: And for that you necro a six-year-old answer?

Comment: @SpyrosMourelatos: I didn't say that. I said that I (pesonally) dislike `#ifdef`. In most Unix-ish software, `#ifdef` has been over-/abused to the point where it gets really hard to see which parts are actually compiled and which aren't. And half the time those `#ifdef`'s don't actually check what the author thought they would. Also, many of the things that are `#ifdef`'ed (platform dependencies) usually impact linker phase / library selection as well. So why not have and handle them at one central point (CMakeLists.txt), together with e.g. version numbers, author contact info...