# Make cmake pass command line variable to compiler

Tags: c++, cmake

I have following code:

```
int main() {
#ifdef COMMIT_VERSION
   cout << "app version: " << COMMIT_VERSION << endl;
#endif
}
```

I would like to invoke cmake such that it passes COMMIT_VERSION variable defined on command line to g++ and thus to my application. E.g. 
following invocation:

```
cmake -WHAT_IS_THE_OPTION_NAME COMMIT_VERSION='"Hello Version"'
make
./a.out
```

produces output

```
app version: Hello Version
```

Comment: You probably want the [`configure_file`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/configure_file.html) function.

Comment: Due to quite convoluted build system. I would prefer not to use files just command line argument passing.

Comment: Perhaps related (or a duplicate): http://stackoverflow.com/q/7900661/417197

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the `-D <var>:<type>=<value>` option to add a definition within the cmake script (`type` and `value` being optional), like so:

```
cmake -D COMMIT_VERSION='"whatever version here"' ...
```

Then, inside the script, you can use the [`add_definitions`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command%3aadd_definitions) function to pass the definition to g++:

```
add_definitions(-DCOMMIT_VERSION=${COMMIT_VERSION})
```

Comment: Using this solution I would have to provide COMMIT_VERSION to cmake as I previously wanted. It turned out that it would be more suitable if I could provide COMMIT_VERSION to make instead of cmake. Is it possible with cmake?