# Use value from C/C++ macro in CMake

Tags: cmake, c-preprocessor

What is the easiest way to get the value of a C/C++ macro into a CMake variable?

Given I check for a library `libfoo` with the header `foo.h`. I know `foo.h` contains the macro `#define FOO_VERSION_MAJOR <version>` where version is an integer or string value. To extract the major version of the found library, I want to use the value from this macro.

As a bonus, if the macro is not found, this could indicate a version older then a specific version introducing the version macro.

Comment: You might consider going the other direction: put the definition in CMake, and have CMake generate the .h with the correct replacement. [See this answer for details.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7900862/1417451)

Comment: The problem is, the library is 3rd party, so I don't have any control where informations are placed.

Comment: Ah, makes sense!

Comment: So your software will work with every version of `libfoo`?

Comment: @Bernhard: Once I know the version, I can also warn about unsupported old versions or emit a deprecation warning for supported versions that will lose support in future releases of my software.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd go with `file(READ ...)` to read the header followed by `string(REGEX ...)` to extract desired define.

Example code:

```
file(READ "foo.h" header)
string(REGEX MATCH "#define FOO_MAJOR_VERSION [0-9]+" macrodef "${header}")
string(REGEX MATCH "[0-9]+" FooMajorVersion "${macrodef}")
```

Answer (score 3):

With `try_compile` and the right pragma it is possible to output the value of a pre-processor macro during compile time. CMake can parse the output to get the desired value.

CMake snippet:

```
try_compile(result "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}"
  SOURCES "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/foo-version.cpp"
  OUTPUT_VARIABLE fooversion)
string(REGEX MATCH ": [0-9]+" fooversionshort "${fooversion}")
string(REGEX MATCH "[0-9]+" FooMajorVersion "${fooversionshort}")
```

foo-version.cpp:

```
#include "foo.h"

/* definition to expand macro then apply to pragma message */
#define VALUE_TO_STRING(x) #x
#define VALUE(x) VALUE_TO_STRING(x)
#pragma message(VALUE(FOO_MAJOR_VERSION))

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Good:

- Actual value from the variable, which might be calculated.

Bad:

- Output of macros is only support by some newer compilers.
- Parsing of output might break for untested compilers, as the format changes from compiler version to compiler version.
- Kind of complicated code, verbose code which is difficult to read.

Comment: You can use `CMakeConfigurableFile.in` to generate the file from a CMake string.

To work around the compile-time macro output limitations you might actually generate a full working program with `std::cout << FOO_MAJOR_VERSION << std::endl;` in `main()` , run the program and capture stdout. Benefit of your approach is that you don't need the link step (which costs additional time and might fail if foo.h contains more definitions for example).

Answer (score 1):

The macro expansion can be extracted by using the C preprocessor.
I used this method to extract specific typedef's without needing to know the exact location of the define in the file hierarchy.

Let say that we have this macro defined somewhere in `foo.h`

```
#define FOO_VERSION_MAJOR 666
```

You need to create a helper file `helper.c` with this content

```
#include "foo.h"
int __READ_FOO_MAJOR__ = FOO_VERSION_MAJOR  ;
```

Note that I used a specific pattern `__READ_FOO_MAJOR__` that I will use later as the pattern for a `grep` command

And from `CMakeLists.txt` you have to call the C (C++, etc..) preprocessor and filter its output like this

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
execute_process(
      COMMAND           bash "-c" "${CMAKE_C_COMPILER} -E ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/helper.cpp | grep __READ_FOO_MAJOR__ | awk '{    print $4}'"
      OUTPUT_VARIABLE   FOO_VERSION_MAJOR )
message("From CMake: FOO_VERSION_MAJOR=${FOO_VERSION_MAJOR}")
```

Note that `awk '{    print $4}'` extract the 4th word on the selected line.

When running `cmake` we get this result

```
From CMake: FOO_VERSION_MAJOR=666
```

The short shel pipeline used is built with Unix system V base commands and should run everywhere.